# WCF Data Services 5.2 MaxProtocolVersion

Tags: wcf-data-services

When I set `MaxProtocolVersion` to V3 my service no longer accepts requests stating `MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0`. Response from the service is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 158
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2013 06:57:05 GMT

{"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"nb-NO","value":"The MaxDataServiceVersion '2.0' enter code hereis too low for the response. The lowest supported version is '3.0'."}}}
```

How can a service configured as version 3 handle requests from clients compliant with version 2?

Comment: After you changed the MaxProtocolVersion to V3, did you enable any new features like collection properties, etc. If yes, then once you have V3 protocol features in the service, then you cannot serve down level clients - down level client have no idea how to interpret the payload.